# I am trying to display products per category with pagination and sorting using AJAX and php but I am getting an error as explained below

Tags: php, ajax, sorting, pagination, categories

I have all categories on Navbar. I am trying to show products foreach category when I click on that category. So far the products are getting displayed but those categories that have no products yet, when clicked I get error below

Fatal error
: Uncaught TypeError: usort(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\securefiles\main\producta.php:75 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\securefiles\main\producta.php(75): usort(NULL, 'sortByQuery') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\securefiles\main\categories.php(141): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\securefiles\main\producta.php
on line
75

I don't get that error when clicking on categories that have products.

Pagination is not working for all of them. When I click a page, the window just scrolls to the top.

MY PHP CODE IS BELOW

```
      `$query = "SELECT   sellers.room,sellers.seller_id,sellers.image,price,sellers.category_id,sellers.type,sellers.badge,categories.category, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT comments.user_id) AS total, AVG(rating) AS rate,AVG(odds) AS odda FROM sellers 
INNER JOIN categories ON sellers.category_id=categories.id 
LEFT JOIN comments ON sellers.seller_id=comments.seller_id 
LEFT JOIN posts ON sellers.seller_id=posts.seller_id
LEFT JOIN keywords ON sellers.seller_id=keywords.seller_id
WHERE categories.id = '$_GET['category_id']'
GROUP BY sellers.seller_id ORDER BY rate DESC";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //PDO::FETCH_OBJ
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
if($result) {
    foreach($result as $product) {
        $products[]=$product;
    }

}
    // Filter query
    $cat_filter = isset($_POST['category_id']) ? $_POST['category_id'] : '';
    $seller_filter = isset($_POST['level']) ? $_POST['level'] : '';
    $sub_filter = isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : '';
    $search_filter = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';

    // Default limit
    $limit = isset($_POST['per-page']) ? $_POST['per-page'] : 3;

    // Default offset
    $offset = 0;
    $current_page = 1;
    if(isset($_POST['page-number'])) {
        $current_page = (int)$_POST['page-number'];
        $offset = ($current_page * $limit) - $limit;
    }

    // filter products array based on query
    if(!empty($seller_filter) || !empty($seller_filter) || !empty($sub_filter) || !empty($search_filter)) {
        $filtered_products = array();
        foreach($products as $product) {
            if(!empty($cat_filter) && !empty($seller_filter) && !empty($sub_filter) && !empty($search_filter)) {

                if((strpos($product['tag_name'], $search_filter) !== false || $product['room'] == $search_filter) && ($product['category_id'] == $cat_filter) && ($product['type'] == $sub_filter) && ($product['badge'] == $seller_filter)) {
                    $filtered_products[] = $product;
                }

            } elseif(!empty($cat_filter) && $product['category_id'] == $cat_filter && !empty($sub_filter) && $product['type'] == $sub_filter) {

                $filtered_products[] = $product;
            } elseif(!empty($cat_filter) && $product['category_id'] == $cat_filter && !empty($seller_filter) && $product['badge'] == $seller_filter) {

                $filtered_products[] = $product;
            } elseif(!empty($search_filter) && (strpos($product['tag_name'], $search_filter) !== false || $product['room'] == $search_filter) && !empty($cat_filter) && $product['category_id'] == $cat_filter) {

                $filtered_products[] = $product;
            }
        }

        $products = $filtered_products;
    }
// Sorting
function sortByQuery($a, $b) {

    $sort_by = isset($_POST['sort-by']) ? $_POST['sort-by'] : 'room';
    $sort_order = isset($_POST['sort-order']) ? $_POST['sort-order'] : 'ASC';

    if ($sort_order == 'DESC') {
        return $a[$sort_by] < $b[$sort_by];
    } else {
        return $a[$sort_by] > $b[$sort_by];
    }
}

usort($products, 'sortByQuery');

// Alter the array
$paged_products = array_slice($products, $offset, $limit);

// Define total products
$total_products = count($products);

// Get the total pages rounded up the nearest whole number
$total_pages = ceil( $total_products / $limit );

$paged = $total_products > count($paged_products) ? true : false;

if (count($paged_products)) {
    foreach ($paged_products as $product) { ?>
                    <div class="card col-sm-3 me-1 mt-3 product-wrapper"  style="width:12.7rem;height: 22rem;">
                        <?php echo '<a href=main/products.php?category='.preg_replace('#[-]+#','-',trim($product['category'])).'&room='.preg_replace('#[-]+#','-',trim($product ['room'])).'&seller_id='.preg_replace('#[-]+#','-',trim($product ['seller_id'])).'>
                        <img src="../seller/' .htmlspecialchars($product ['image']).'" class="img-top  img-fluid bg-light" alt="...">
                        </a>';?> 
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row border-bottom">
                                <h5 class="card-title text-center fw-bolder fs-5 mt-3"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['room']);?></h5>
                                <p class="text-center text-decoration-none text-dark"  style="font-size:1rem;" ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['category']);?></p>
                                <p class="text-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['rate']);?>
                                    <span class="text-end fw-light text-dark">(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['total']);?>)</span>
                                </p>
                            </div><p class="card-title text-start fw-bolder text-decoration-none text-dark"                  style="font-size:0.7rem;">STARTING AT
                            <span class="text-start fw-bolder text-decoration-underline" style="font-size:.8rem;">US &dollar;<?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['price']);?></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <?php }
                }

                else {
                    echo '<p class="alert alert-warning" >No results found.</p>';
                 } 
                if ($paged) {
                    require('pagination.php');
                }
```

MY PAGINATION SCRIPT

```
<?php
    $current_query = isset($_POST) ? 'data-query="' . http_build_query($_POST) . '"' : '';
?>
<nav class="col-md-12 mt-3" >
  <ul class="pagination">
      
        <li class="page-item <?php echo $current_page === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" data-page-number="<?php echo $current_page - 1; ?>" <?php echo $current_query; ?> >
            <span>«</span>
          </a>
        </li>
    
    <?php
    
    for($page_number = 1; $page_number <= $total_pages; $page_number ++) { ?>
             <li class="page-item <?php echo isset($_POST['page-number']) && $_POST['page-number'] == $page_number ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page-number="<?php echo $page_number; ?>" <?php echo $current_query; ?>><?php echo $page_number; ?></a></li>
    
    <?php } ?>
    
        <li class="page-item <?php echo $current_page === (int)$total_pages ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" data-page-number="<?php echo $current_page + 1; ?>" <?php echo $current_query; ?>>
            <span>»</span>
          </a>
        </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

MY AJAX SCRIPT FOR ECHOING DATA ON THE PAGE

```
$(document).on('change', '#category_id', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("category_id");

        $.ajax({
            url:"producta.php?category_id="+id, 
            method:"POST",    
            data:{'category_id':id},
            success:function(data){
                $('#all-products').html(data);
            }
        })
        $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(){
            var page_number = $(this).data('page-number');
            var current_query;
            if( $(this).data('query') ) {
            current_query = '?' + $(this).data('query');
            }
            else {
                current_query = '';
            }
            $.ajax({
                    url:"producta.php?" + current_query , 
                    method:"POST",   
                    data:{'page-number' : page_number},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#all-products').html(data);
                    }
             })
             $(document).on('submit', '#filter-form', function(){
                var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url:"producta.php?category_id="+id,  
                    method:"POST",   
                    data : $('#form').serialize() + "&category_id="+id ,
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#all-products').html(data);
                    }
             })
             });
        });
    });
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 1):

If your query don't find any record, the code surrounded by your if:

```
if($result) {
    
    foreach($result as $product) {
        $products[]=$product;
    }

}
```

is not executed, so *$products* doesn't exist and it's evaluated as NULL.
To quicky solve the problem initialize $products as empty array:

```
$products = [];

if($result) {
   //...
```

However I must warn you that your code is poorly optimized and you face SQL injection.

I see you use a prepared statement but then use string concatenation to compose the query instead of using parameters, this is a bad approach which exposes you to SQL injection

In my opinion it is also pointless to copy the query result to a new array, row by row:

```
foreach($result as $product) {
     $products[]=$product;
}
```

you can use the fetch result directly (`$result`)

Furthermore pagination, sorting and data filters must be performed directly in the query, it is not convenient to read all the rows from the DB and then filter them in the code: imagine having to act on thousands of lines...